# How to separate full name string into firstname and lastname string?

Tags: c#, string, string-parsing

I need some help with this, I have a fullname string and what I need to do is separate and use this fullname string as firstname and lastname separately.

Comment: In which language? English? What do you want to do with Middle names? What do you want to do with "Mr." and "Jr." or "Dr. Juan D. Garcia y Lopez Jr., M.D."?

Comment: Do you have a separator? `"Edimar*Lima", * = separator`

Comment: If you don't show us what your actual strings look like, there is little we can do to help you.

Comment: As John pointed out, names can be tricky. Depending on your use case it might be better to either avoid splitting the name or design your UI so that your users do the splitting themselves.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This will work if you are sure you have a first name and a last name.

```
string fullName = "Adrian Rules";
var names = fullName.Split(' ');
string firstName = names[0];
string lastName = names[1];
```

Make sure you check for the length of `names`.

```
names.Length == 0 //will not happen, even for empty string
names.Length == 1 //only first name provided (or blank)
names.Length == 2 //first and last names provided
names.Length > 2 //first item is the first name. last item is the last name. Everything else are middle names
```

**Update**

Of course, this is a rather simplified view on the problem. The objective of my answer is to explain how `string.Split()` works. However, you must keep in mind that some last names are composite names, like "Luis da Silva", as noted by @AlbertEin.

This is far from being a simple problem to solve. Some prepositions (in french, spanish, portuguese, etc.) are part of the last name. That's why @John Saunders asked "what language?". John also noted that prefixes (Mr., Mrs.) and suffixes (Jr., III, M.D.) might get in the way.

Comment: Your last name is Rules? shaweet.

Comment: I would like that woudn't I? It's not though... :( But I'm happy it's not "Sucks" :)

Comment: There was an error in the code. I fixed it. Downvoter, please revise.

Comment: "names.Length > 2 //at index 0 lies first name. At index Length-1, lies last name.": That's not true!, it's possible to not have middle names but have a last name composed with more than one word.

Comment: @AlbertEin, what do you mean?

Comment: @Adrian For example "Pedro de la Garza", first name: "Pedro", last name: "De la Garza". N

Comment: What if thr name is "Juan Carlos" both are part of the firstname

Comment: I'm sorry, but for that case, first name is Juan

Comment: late here but adding a formula that is done in excel to get John Doe from John.Doe, John_Doe , John123Doe  https://chandoo.org/wp/extract-first-name-last-name-from-email/ perhaps a translation to C# could be useful.

Comment: Simple yet complete, comprehensive and logical answer. Nowadays, most people would suggest applying AI to solve the problem!!!

Answer (score 18):

You could try to parse it using spaces but it's not going to work, Example:

```
var fullName = "Juan Perez";
var name = fullName.Substring(0, fullName.IndexOf(" "));
var lastName = fullName.Substring(fullName.IndexOf(" ") + 1);
```

But that would fail with a ton of user input, what about if he does have two names? "Juan Pablo Perez".

Names are complicated things, so, it's not possible to always know what part is the first and last name in a given string.

**EDIT**

You should not use string.Split method to extract the last name, some last names are composed from two or more words, as example, a friend of mine's last name is "Ponce de Leon".

Comment: Probably should change your code to use the split method, however you mentioned something that the other didn't that i agree with.

Comment: The problem with split is that if your last name contains spaces you are going to lose part of the name. Example, a friend of mine last name is "Ponce de leon"

Comment: This is far from a simple problem. Want some samples? Thomas Alva Edison: the last name is not Alva Edison. Ponce de Leon: Last name is de Leon. How do you know? Because of the preposition "de". There's "de", "da", etc.

Comment: @Adrian you are wrong, "Ponce de Leon" is the last name, not "de Leon". In fact, it's not possible to do what the OP asked in any kind of reliable way

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It works regardles of the number of middle names.

Comment: This will also need check if only 1 name provided. For example 
fullName = "Perez";

Answer (score 16):

This solution will work for people that have a last name that has more than one word. Treat the first word as the first name and leave everything else as the last name.

```
public static string getLastNameCommaFirstName(String fullName) {
    List<string> names = fullName.Split(' ').ToList();
    string firstName = names.First();
    names.RemoveAt(0);

    return String.Join(" ", names.ToArray()) + ", " + firstName;            
}
```

For Example passing Brian De Palma into the above function will return "De Palma, Brian"

```
getLastNameFirst("Brian De Palma");
//returns "De Palma, Brian"
```

Comment: This will not work for anyone that has a middle name or a first name that includes spaces

Comment: @Rachel613 that might be true but the numbers of names with spaces in the first name would be rare.  On an as whole basis the majority of cases can be better accommodated this way.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [**this version (MSDN)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda(v=vs.110).aspx) of `Split` method like follow:

```
var testcase = "John Doe";
var split = testcase.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 2);
```

In this case `split[0]` will be `John` and `split[1]` will be `Deo`. another example:

```
var testcase = "John Wesley Doe";
var split = testcase.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 2);
```

In this case `split[0]` will be `John` and `split[1]` will be `Wesley Doe`.

*Notice that the length of `split` never be more than 2*

So with following code you can get `FirstName` and `LastName` nicely:

```
var firstName = "";
var lastName = "";
var split = testcase.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 2);
if (split.Length == 1)
{
    firstName = "";
    lastName = split[0];
}
else
{
    firstName = split[0];
    lastName = split[1];
}
```

Hope this answer add something useful to this page.

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
  string fullName = "The mask lol"; 
    string[] names = fullName.Split(' '); 
    string name = names.First();
    string lasName = names.Last();
```

Comment: Why not `string name = names.First();`?

Comment: this is evil solution..  JOhn Van Meter in which 'Van Meter' is surname.  your solution will completely screw the surname

Comment: @user384080: It does what the user requested. It split the first and last name, considering only that they are split into white spaces. He didn't mentioned to consider any other thing,e.g., like it is split in different languages.

Comment: @Filburt: Edited. Sorry for small latence :)

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using a [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30wbz966%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to rigorously define what your first and last names look like.

Answer (score 4):

There are several implementations of name parsing/splitting over at nuget. If you dive into the NameParserSharp repository you can also just combine two partial classes and copy & paste into your own library.

[NameParserSharp](https://github.com/aeshirey/NameParserSharp)

[More at Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=name%2C+parser)

Answer (score 3):

name ="Tony Stark is dead";

```
get_first_name(String name) {
    var names = name.split(' ');
    String first_name= "";
 
    for (int i = 0; i != names.length; i++) {
      if (i != names.length - 1) 
      {
        if (i == 0) {
          first_name= first_name+ names[i];
        } else {
          first_name= first_name+ " " + names[i];
        }
      }
    }
    return first_name; // Tony Stark is
  }



  get_last_name(String name) {
    var names = name.split(' ');
    return names[names.length - 1].toString(); // dead
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a piece of c# code that I use on my projects. It returns the last word as surname and the rest as name.

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/taTnhP)

**Output:**

```
Mary Isobel Catherine O’Brien
-------------------------
Name : Mary Isobel Catherine , Surname : O’Brien
```

P.S. No middle name, sorry.

```
public static string[] SplitFullNameIntoNameAndSurname(string pFullName)
{
    string[] NameSurname = new string[2];
    string[] NameSurnameTemp = pFullName.Split(' ');
    for (int i = 0; i < NameSurnameTemp.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i < NameSurnameTemp.Length - 1)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(NameSurname[0]))
                NameSurname[0] += " " + NameSurnameTemp[i];
            else
                NameSurname[0] += NameSurnameTemp[i];
        }
        else
            NameSurname[1] = NameSurnameTemp[i];
    }
    return NameSurname;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this as simple as calling [string.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx), passing a single space as the split character?  Or is there something trickier going on here?  (If the latter, please update your question with more info.)

Answer (score 0):

for basic use cases its easy to just split on ' ' or ', ' however due to the variety of names with differing things in them this is not going to always work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to port this PHP lib https://github.com/joshfraser/PHP-Name-Parser/blob/master/parser.php

Answer (score 0):

So if you take the First space as Name and rest as Surname, this would give us

```
Person myPerson = new Person();

Misc tidyup = new Misc();
string[] result = tidyup.SplitFullName(tb1.Text);

foreach (string s in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);

    if (result.First() == s)
    {
        myPerson.FirstName = s;
    }
    else
    {
        myPerson.LastName += s + " ";
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        Console.WriteLine(myPerson.LastName);
    }
}    

public string[] SplitFullName(string myName)
{
    string[] names = myName.Split(' ');
    //string firstName = names[0];
    //string lastName = names[1];

    return names;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy, simple code to transform something like **Flowers, Love** to **Love Flowers** (this works with very complex names such as **Williams Jones, Rupert John**):

```
        string fullname = "Flowers, Love";
        string[] fullnameArray = fullname.Split(",");//Split specify a separator character, so it's removed
        for (int i = fullnameArray.Length - 1; i >= fullnameArray.Length - 2; i--)
        {
                Write($"{fullnameArray[i].TrimStart() + " "}");
        }
```

**output**: Love Flowers

The other way around. Love Flowers converted to Flowers, Love:

```
        string fullname = "Love Flowers";
        int indexOfTheSpace = fullname.IndexOf(' ');
        string firstname = fullname.Substring(0, indexOfTheSpace);
        string lastname = fullname.Substring(indexOfTheSpace + 1);
        WriteLine($"{lastname}, {firstname}");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one method for this. My specific situation is solved with a code example like below.

**for Example**

---

> if there is only one space in the user's name.

```
 int idx = fullName.IndexOf(' '); //This customer name : Osman Veli
```

> if there is more than one space in the user's name.

```
 if (fullName.Count(Char.IsWhiteSpace) > 1)
 {
    idx = fullName.LastIndexOf(' '); //This customer name : Osman Veli Sağlam
 }

  if (idx != -1)
  {
    // Osman Veli Sağlam
    firstName = fullName.Substring(0, idx); // FirstName: Osman Veli 
    lastName = fullName.Substring(idx + 1); // LastName : Sağlam
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a value object to represent a name and use it in your application

```
public class Name
{
    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }
    public string FullName { get; }

    public Name(string name)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            return;

        FullName = name;

        LoadFirstAndLastName();
    }

    private void LoadFirstAndLastName()
    {
        var names = FullName.Trim().Split(" ", 2);

        FirstName = names.First();

        if (names.Count() > 1)
            LastName = names.Last();
    }

    public override string ToString() => FullName;

    //Enables implicit set (Name name = "Rafael Silva")
    public static implicit operator Name(string name) => new Name(name);
}
```

Usages:

```
Name name = "Jhon Doe"; //FirstName = Jhon - LastName = Doe
Name name = new Name("Jhon Doe"); //FirstName = Jhon - LastName = Doe    
Name name = new Name("Rafael Cristiano da Silva"); //FirstName = Rafael - LastName = Cristiano da Silva

//On class property
public Name Name {get; set; } = "Jhon Doe";
```

Comment: Shouldn't Split(" ", 2) actually be Split(' ', 2) because it takes a char not a string as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Better to be late than never, here is my solution for this used in many applications.

```
 string fullName = "John De Silva";
 string[] names = fullName.Split(" ");
 string firstName = names.First(); // John
 string lastName = string.Join(" ", names.Skip(1).ToArray()); // De Silva
```

Enjoy !

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub SplitFullName(Full_Name As String)

        Dim names = Full_Name.Split(" ")
        Dim FirstName As String = ""
        Dim MiddletName As String = ""
        Dim LastName As String = ""
        If names.Count = 0 Then
            FirstName = ""
            MiddletName = ""
            LastName = ""
        ElseIf names.Count = 1 Then
            FirstName = names(0)
        ElseIf names.Count = 2 Then
            FirstName = names(0)
            LastName = names(1)
        Else
            FirstName = names(0)
            For i = 1 To names.Count - 2
                MiddletName += " " & names(i)
            Next
            LastName = names(names.Count - 1)
        End If
        MsgBox("The first name is: " & FirstName & ";   The middle name is: " & MiddletName & ";    The last name is: " & LastName)

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect Working

Answer (score 0):

I've added some more check to get the desired result
for example other solution work but when i intentionally take two spaces it do not work, so here is workaround.

```
final name = ' sambhav';
final words = name.trim().split(' ');
final firstName = words[0];
final lastName = words.length > 1 ? words[words.length - 1] : '';
print('first name : $firstName, last name : $lastName');
```

Result

```
input : Sambhav jain // first name : Sambhav, last name : jain    
input : Sambhav the jain // first name : Sambhav, last name : jain  
input : Sambhav // first name : Sambhav, last name :
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my extension. It returns the last word as the last name and the rest as the first name.

```
public static void SplitFullName(this string fullName, out string firstName, out string lastName)
{
    firstName = string.Empty;
    lastName = string.Empty;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fullName))
    {

        lastName = string.Empty; firstName = string.Empty;
        int splitIndex = fullName.LastIndexOf(' ');
        if (splitIndex >= 0)
        {
            firstName = fullName.Substring(0, splitIndex);
            lastName = fullName.Substring(splitIndex + 1);
        }
        else
            firstName = fullName;
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
"Micheal".SplitFullName(out string first, out string last);
// first = "Micheal"
// last = ""

"Micheal Jackson".SplitFullName(out string first, out string last);
// first = "Micheal"
// last = "Jackson"

"Micheal Joseph Jackson".SplitFullName(out string first, out string last);
// first = "Micheal Joseph"
// last = "Jackson"
```

On a side note *Visual Studio Intellisense* is getting out of hand! I only wrote the code up to the `if` condition and the rest was completed by Intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in dart/flutter:

```
var fullName = 'Jawad Hussain Abbasi';

firstName = fullName.split(' ')[0];

lastName = fullName.split(' ').skip(1).join(" ");

log('First Name: $firstName'); // Jawad

log('Last Name: $lastName'); // Hussain Abbasi
```